Does the GDPR right to deletion in Art. 17 effectively include some "disproportionate effort" exception?
Some provisions of the GDPR have explicit exceptions about "disproportionate effort".  Particularly relevant is the one in Article 19:

The controller shall communicate any rectification or erasure of personal data or restriction of processing carried out in accordance with Article 16, Article 17(1) and Article 18 to each recipient to whom the personal data have been disclosed, unless this proves impossible or involves disproportionate effort.

There is no such explicit exception in the text of Article 17, Right to erasure.  While paragraph 3 includes a number of exceptions, none relate to the difficulty of the task or the extent of the loss that would have to be born.  Does that mean it is absolute, such that there is no lengths they cannot be asked to go to, no loss that is so great that the company cannot be asked to face if required to effectively delete personal information?
One possible hypothetical where this could be relevant is highlighted by the news that meta is planning to train a Generative AI on its database in an opt out manner.  While it is far from certain, it is quite conceivable that if they go ahead with this plan at some point in the future it will be found that this leaks personal information and the only way to delete anyone's data is to delete all the data.  Whereas this potential is particularly obvious as it applies to Meta, it could conceivably apply to any Generative AI trained on the internet.
Would there be a limit to what a company could be asked to do to delete some amount of data?  Would it matter if they spent 1 million or 10 billion on building a database?  Would it matter that other companies relied on using it and were "making the world better"?  Would it matter if it leaked 1 in 10 peoples data, or 1 in a million, or 1?

None of the main GDPR data subject rights have a "disproportionate effort" exception. However, some notification requirements in Arts 14(5)(b), 17(2), or 19 are limited. In your AI training example, the legal basis would probably be a legitimate interest. Art 17 requires at least one condition in 17(1) to hold, and none of the exceptions in 17(3). Deletion could be refused for "overriding legitimate grounds" that overrule an objection to a legitimate interest. No Art 17(1)(c), thus no deletion would be needed. I think the effort to retrain a model could constitute overriding grounds.
